# RDS Connectivity Issue with EKS Cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-eks, aws-security-group

I have an RDS PSQL Database which is open to all connections as shown in the screenshot attached below and it is also in the same VPC as my EKS Cluster which is also visible.

I am running a rails app in my EKS cluster and trying to create a Database and have already set my RDS Cluster end-point in Environment Variables.

Command I am using: `kubectl exec -it pod/app-b65785bd5-r8mpj --  bundle exec rails db:create`

Both EKS CLuster and RDS are in the same VPC `vpc-0f9737b08c3269c4d` and I also White-listed the EKS Cluster IP Address in the Security Group of RDS Cluster Database following is the error I am getting.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJCdP.png)

[RDS Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibv0v.png)

[RDS Security Group In-bound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sCG3.png)

[RDS Security Group Out-bound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClxWi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your RDS hostname resolved to `10.0.2.75` most likely your VPC CIDR  range is 10/16. Modify inbound rules in your DB SG to allow traffic from `10.0.0.0/16`

Comment: I resolved it yesterday by adding the VPC Security Group to the in-bound rules of the RDS cluster security group.

um, and how did you check what the RDS hostname resolved to ?

Comment: I allowed it from my whole VPC, still it is not connecting.